# htaccess take action based on directory location

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file in my project. I have a total of 4 environments currently. I want to enforce basic authentication on one of them. I'm managing versions of my environments with git.

I want to use the same .htaccess file in each environment so I'm looking for similar logic as below:

```
if localpath = env_x
    prompt authorization
else
    do nothing extra
```

Is something like this obtainable in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`If`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if) for conditional parts in the Apache configuration. In your case this could be

```
<If %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =~ /env_x/>
# basic auth directives
</If>
```

See also [Expressions in Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) for what is possible.

Comment: Thanks, that seems easy enough.